# Laravel: relations on same table

Tags: php, laravel

In my application I have a `users` table, in this table there is a field called `managedByUsername` which is the username of that particular user's manager.

To get your employees specifically you could perform a query as follows:

`$employees = User::where('managedByUsername', auth()->user->username)->get()`

To get your manager, on the User model you could have the relation;

```
public function mananager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'username', 'managedByUsername');
}
```

However, I can't think of how you would do this the other way around?

Perhaps

```
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'username', 'managedByUsername');
}
```

But this obviously wouldn't work.

I have also tried the following:

```
/**
 * Get the manager for this user
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function mananager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'managedByUsername', 'username');
}

/**
 * Get the manager for this user
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'managedByUsername', 'username');
}
```

Comment: You need to match by primary key. not by name.

Comment: The first set of relation are wrong second ones are correct.Can you post your code used for fetching?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to solve this problem would be to use the id of the user as the foreign key for manager.

So replace `managedByUsername` field with `manager_id`.

Then, you can write your Eloquent relations as:

```
public function mananager()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'manager_id');
}

public function employees()
{
  return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'manager_id');
}
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.

Comment: I suggest you to use id as key instead of text, simply because it's shorter. However, if you insist on using username, replace manager_id in my answer with managedByUsername and you are good to go.

Comment: For some weird reason I get trying to get property of non object on my updated question, despite the fact I've specified both the foreign and other key...